# Is VB6 string comparison case insensitive?

Tags: string, vb6

if strValue = 'Hello' then what would be the value of (strValue <> 'HELLO') be?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier - and more certain - to write an incredibly simple test for this?

Comment: Carl, I was about to say that.  Most people don't have a VB6 interpreter around, but the OP obviously does. :)

Comment: Though VBA behaves the same and most people do have that...

Comment: @Carl - Sure, simple unit tests on classic ASP VB code with no reliable debugging tool sound great.  Or you could not put a comment here and actually answered the question.

Comment: I'm joking. i don't have a vb6 environment set up and literally looking at code with sourcesafe's viewer.

Comment: @"Typosaurus" ;) VBA doesn't always behave the same as VB6. Access has Option Compare Database which doesn't exist in VB6. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98227

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I assumed in this respect at least VB6 and VBA were consistent.

Comment: @CarlManaster No it wouldn't be quicker to find it out by testing. Because the answer can depend on optional compiler directives at the top of the source file. Good luck figuring *that* out by testing. Reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212267.aspx), though, that's quicker

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on how you use the [Option Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266181(v=vs.60).aspx) statement. It can work either way.

```
Option Compare Text 'Case insensitive'
Option Compare Binary 'Case sensitive (default)'
```

Here's a [VB6 string tutorial](http://www.vbexplorer.com/VBExplorer/Focus/strings_tutorial_2.asp).

Answer (score 11):

No, it's case sensitive (by default at least though you'll want to check - if Option Compare is set to Binary or not set then it's case sensitive, if it's set to text then it's case insensitive).

Lcase() both sides if you'd rather it were case insensitive.

The reason I prefer this to changing / setting option compare is that someone looking at the code doesn't have to go hunting to see what option compare is set to to understand how it's going to behave BUT it's almost certainly slower (not significantly unless you're calling it repeatedly) and some might see it as not particularly neat.

Comment: or UCase would do the same thing.

Comment: Or use StrComp(strVal1, strVal2, vbTextCompare)

Comment: Might be worth saying that the reason I do this rather than use option compare is that I prefer to make it explicit in the comparison rather than have someone reading the code find something which modified the default behaviour.

Comment: Partly wrong, it's not always case sensitive. It depends on the Option Compare setting in the source file. (As you obviously know from your comment - you might want to modify your answer?) Another reason for avoiding non-default Option Compare settings is it lays a trap for anyone who copies the routines to another project.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212267.aspx) is fairly clear

> If you use `Option Compare Text` in the Declarations section of a
>   module [the top of the file], string comparisons aren't case-sensitive.
>   If you use `Option Compare Binary`, comparisons are case-sensitive.
>   If you use `Option Compare Database` [*only valid in Access VBA*], the comparison method is set by the current database.

Comment: Hello whoever downvoted this. Care to leave a comment?